# Gralloc]: lock_ycbcr: videobuffer_status is invalid, use default value

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-camera2, textureview

I am getting this:

> Gralloc]: lock_ycbcr: videobuffer_status is invalid, use default value

from the logcat.
I am using TextureView and camera2

what does in mean?

Comment: post your code. It can be easy to answer.

Comment: solve, by restart camera thread